# Set of Accounts targeted for a promotion with no sales

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have 2 fact tables, a sales transaction fact and and a Daily snapshot Fact. The purpose of the snapshot is to see which accounts were targeted for a specific promotion.
I am wanting to create a set to display the accounts that were targeted, but didn't have a transaction. Any help is appreciated.

This is what I attempted, but wasn't really close to getting it right. I don't want the set to display a measure, just the list of Accounts.

```
create set [targeted] AS
Distinct ([Account].[Account].[Account],[Measures].[SnapshotMeasure]);
create set [transacted] AS
Distinct ([Account].[Account].[Account],[Measures].[SalesMeasure]);
create set [targeted no sales] as
EXCEPT([targeted],[transacted] );
```

Comment: Did you look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145963.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to add this to your cube script.

Maybe something like the following:

```
CREATE SET [NameOfYourCube].[targeted] AS 
  Filter([Account].[Account].[Account], [Measures].[SnapshotMeasure] > 0)
CREATE SET [NameOfYourCube].[transacted] AS 
  Filter([Account].[Account].[Account], [Measures].[SalesMeasure] > 0)
CREATE SET [NameOfYourCube].[targeted no sales] AS 
  EXCEPT([targeted],[transacted])
```